# Trying to find shadow-content tag in Google search page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the value of the `contenteditable` attribute under the child division of `shadow-content`.

On the Google Search page I am able to find the `Shadow-Content` tag under `<textarea>` when I am using the Safari browser.

This `shadow-content` tag is **not** available in Chrome, Firefox and Explorer.

[image]

Comment: Mr. are you trying to hack google ?

Comment: `shadow-content` is not a tag. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM